# Puppeteer not launching chromium in Mac 10.14

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I am trying to open a page through puppeteer but it's not throwing any error and entire code is getting executed by chromium doesn't show up.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
console.log('there');
await page.goto('https://google.com');
console.log('yes');
//   await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

//   await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quote from the [Puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer):

> Puppeteer launches Chromium in headless mode. To launch a full version of Chromium, set the 'headless' option when launching a browser:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false}); // default is true
```

“Headless” means when your code is executed, you won't actually see any browser window, the code is run in the browser purely on the command line.